# Why does Weka's Experimenter not show the results from all 10 folds?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am using Weka to run a decision tree classifier on a set of data.  I am using 10-fold cross validation and I want to know the individual accuracies of each of the ten folds.  Under Classify on the Explorer I can get a big long list of each of the predictions on test data.  This means I have to manually add up all the +'s.

This will take a long time especially if there is a lot of data.  As well it is easy to make mistakes.

Under Experimenter I can set up a 10-fold cross-validation classifier on the same data (with 1 repetition).  I can set the 'row' to 'folds' and then when I go to 'column' and set it as 'number_incorrect' it is only showing me 6 of the ten folds.

So how do I get the correct number for all 10 folds and why is it doing this?

Answer (score 2):

In the Analyse tab you should select:

1) Rows: **fold**

2) Columns: you must select **Run**, **Fold** and **your wanted results**.

If you omit one of the options in section two you will see only partial information.

Answer (score 0):

The way Weka is doing this, in my understanding, is that, in a K-fold cross validation (CV), an individual accuracy of a single fold is not that meaningful. The whole idea of K-fold CV to simply split the data into K subsets and leave out each fold in turn for validation. Then the validation error is calculated as an **average** across K-fold, which is an **unbiased estimate** of the error of our learning algorithm.

Refer to the link below for more details:
https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~cis520/wiki/index.php?n=Lectures.Overfitting

Comment: Yes, but if you want to compare two classifiers with a signed ranked test, you might want to use the accuracy of all the folds.